Which Chopped episode has this line, which is shown in the opening credits?
For one season of Chopped, the opening credits shows Scott Conant telling a contestant during judging:

It's a poor representation of an entire culture.

This opening sequence is played through the entire season, and through a google search for the phrase, I have been able to narrow it down to season 18. But I have been unable to identify exactly which episode this line is spoken during the judging.

The original episode that line appears to be paraphrased from is "Firefighter Chefs" , Season 18 Episode 6. 

Firefighters compete and get the meal started with some hearty
  meat-and-cheese appetizers. Will the judges enjoy them? Then in the
  entree round, some big errors with a non-basket-ingredient gets one of
  the judges upset.

From the transcript as posted:

I love what you did with the wild boar chop. The char on the grill
  provides a much-needed flavor. I think it is slightly underdone. Two
  more minutes, it would have been perfect. But I want to talk pasta.
  It's a poor representation, frankly, of an entire culture. You have
  Italian background, right?  
Yes. 
Um, what happened? Why did you allow it to cook for 27 minutes?  
I -- I know. I just panicked.

